Seeing the error "User not found in the user store." with error code 404 on making the call to the GET API https://localhost:9443/scim2/Users/userId
I'm using WSO2 REST APIs for various functionalities including updating credentials. First of all I make a call to the GET API https://localhost:9443/api/identity/user/v1.0/pi-info/{Base64 encoded userName} which successfully returns the unique userId from the identity server. This userId is then used in the SCIM2 API for GET/PUT/PATCH calls. But all of those API calls fail with the 404 error, when of course, the user is present in the user store. Is there some WSO2 IS configuration that I should be looking into or anything else that might be missing?
I checked the WSO2 dashboard and the userId is definitely present in the user store. It's WSO2 5.11.0 and the user used in authorization for making the REST call has all permissions(list,view,update). Thanks!

Do you get this error just only for one user? Can you try GET https://localhost:9443/scim2/Users API and see whether this user is listed and what is the id returned in the response? Also mention the userstore type that you use (LDAP, AD, JDBC), and how the user get onboarded (Did you created the user from mgt console/ scim API/ self registered the user/ connected the user record existing userstore?)
